# jQuery Ajax Progress - how to not inherit progress percentage on different ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress, percentage

Hi i'm actually using this plugin https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress/

It simply adds a progress: statment to ajax request.

It works great and my code looks like this:

```
var _min_width = 470;
var _min_height = 330;
var _which;
var _fyle_type;
var _file_name;
var allowed_types = new Array('image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg');
if (typeof(FileReader) === 'function'){
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e) {
     _file_name = $(this).val();

    var file = e.target.files[0];

    if (!in_array(file.type,allowed_types) || file.length === 0){
        notify("You must select a valid image file!",false,false); 
        return;
    }

    if(file.size > 3145728 /*3MB*/){
        notify("<?php echo lang('each-photo-1MB'); ?>",false,false); 
        return;
    }
    notify_destroy();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileOnload;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);


});

function fileOnload(e) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.target.result;

    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if(img.width < _min_width || img.height < _min_height ){
        notify("<?php echo lang('each-photo-1MB'); ?>",false,false); 
        return;
        }

       //remove not-needed base64 data:pfff
       var clear_string =  e.target.result.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','').replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
       var _data;
       if(_which == 'photo_1'){
        _data = {photo_1:clear_string};
       }if(_which == 'photo_2'){
        _data = {photo_2:clear_string};
       }if(_which == 'photo_3'){
        _data = {photo_3:clear_string};
       }if(_which == 'photo_4'){
        _data = {photo_4:clear_string};
       }
            $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            dataType:'text',
            data:_data,
            url:_config_base_url+'/upload/upload_photos',
            beforeSend:function(){
            $('.'+_which+'_holder').fadeOut(0);
            $('.'+_which+'_progress').fadeIn(0);
            $('.'+_which+'_progress').addClass('progress-striped');
            },  
            progress:function(e){
            //make sure we can compute the length
            if(e.lengthComputable) {
            //calculate the percentage loaded
            var pct = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;

            $('.'+_which+'_progress .bar').css({'width':pct+'%'});
            $('.'+_which+'_progress .progress-opt span').text(pct.toFixed(0));
            //console.log(pct);
            }else {
            console.warn('Content Length not reported!');
            }
            },
            success:function(){
            alert(_file_name+' uploaded ok');
            },
            complete:function(){
            $('.'+_which+'_progress .progress-opt span').text('100');
            $('.'+_which+'_holder p').text(_file_name);
            $('.'+_which+'_progress .bar').css({'width':'100%'});
            $('.'+_which+'_progress').delay(300).removeClass('progress-striped').fadeOut(0,function(){
            $('.'+_which+'_holder').show(0);
            $('.'+_which+'_progress .bar').css({'width':'0'});
            });


            }
            });


    });

}
}
```

now the problem is when i set `text(pct.toFixed(0))` in the `progress:` ajax statment, i need to make `pct` "live" i mean, this code puts request progress in percentage , so you can see how much in percentage it takes the request to end up.

> The problem is if i launch 2 of these requests the pct gets shared for
>   both requests so if **request 1** is on 40% **progress (pct)** then the **request 2**
>   will **inherit** the same progress percentage(pct = 40%) from  **request 1**

---

### to better explain i would like to launch many of this requests but to > keep progress percentage (**var pct**) unique for each request

Comment: The problem is that `which` has the same value or both sets of ajax progress calls. If you get `which` info a closure unique for each call, it should work. You are going to have the same problem for the `file_name` printed out at the end and the update to the progress at the end.

Comment: @LeeMeador `_which` changes his value on each `change()` so on each request launched then, but i can't do **var _which.pct** !?

Comment: @LeeMeador nope dude, the _file_name always new on each request, check better i already tested and it works, just the problem is to make pct not shared :P

Comment: @LeeMeador sorry my mistake i pasted the enteire js now it's clear i think..

Answer (score 1):

This will store the value of `_which` for reuse when the handlers get called:

```
function(_which, file_name) {
    $.ajax(... same as the code you have ...
}(_which, file_name);
```

What this does is create a closure that holds the values of the two variables you use in the callback (handler) functions you pass to the ajax call. By doing this you are still sharing the functions (e.g. progress) but you are not sharing the values of `_which` and `file_name` that are used in those functions.

You would, of course, be adding the 1st and 3rd lines around your entire call toe `$.ajax`

If you add more variables that are set outside but used inside those handler functions, you will need to add them to the closure as well.

There are other ways to do this but this is minimal change to your code.

For example this would work too:

```
var doAjax = function() {
    var localWhich = _which;
    var localFileName = file_name;
    $.ajax(... all the same code but use localWhich where you have _which now
         ... and localFileName where you have file_name now
}
doAjax();
```

Comment: so i need to put ajax in a method with params ? will this not share the progress: statment? I'm little bit newbie, if you can add a little description of why it works it's great man! ;) @Lee Meador